# Use IQueryable.OrderBy for a composite key without loading all the items?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I am retrieving some tuples from a database that are mapped to entity classes by means of Entity Framework.

For these entities, I have a key selector function (supplied at runtime by other developers) that I would like to pass to [`Queryable.OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549264(v=vs.110).aspx). The key selector function is provided upon "registration" of the entity type in my system - which happens by means of a method that looks *roughly* like this:

```
public void RegisterEntity<TEntity, TKey>(string entityName, TKey defaultKey, Func<TEntity, TKey> keySelectorFunc)
```

I would like to execute this `OrderBy` call before materializing the results to entity objects (i.e. in such a way that the `OrderBy` call still gets translated to SQL under the hood).

The problem is that the entities have composite keys, and thus, the key selector function will return a custom object instantiated in the function. You can imagine it like this:

```
var keySelectorFunc = e => new CustomKey(e.Value1, e.Value2);
```

As usual, Entity Framework does not like this (the usual "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities" error).

**Is there any way to use such a custom key selector function to return a custom key?** Do I have to resort to anonymous classes? Or should I move the `OrderBy` call to a place after I have left the LINQ-to-Entities world?

Comment: Where this values (e.Value1 and e.Value2) came from?

Comment: You can use two order by clause one for each column of composite key. Even if, let say, you are able to provide order by for custom key, SQL server will not perform order by on both the columns at the same time. OrderBy and ThenBy should result in proper SQL query and ordering should happen at the SQL server before data is returned to the code.

Comment: @EdneyBatistadaSilva: They are properties of the entity that are mapped to database columns.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: But it's not necessarily that simple - the returned custom key implements `IComparable`; it is not guaranteed that ordering does indeed consider the involved column in any fixed order. For instance (as a bogus example, but just to illustrate), the key might behave in such a way that it sorts ascendingly by `Value1`, except if both `Value2` are negative, in which case it sorts descendingly by `Value1`.

Comment: But if the ordering has to be done at the SQL server then I am not sure if IComparer or IComparable will come in picture. I am not sure if I am missing anything here.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: That may be true; if that is the case, it seems "move the `OrderBy` call to the LINQ-to-objects part of the code" is the correct answer. Having some kind of official reference ("LINQ-to-Entities does not support custom IComparable implements" or similar) would be nice, though.

Comment: EF will not and can not replicate the IComparable implementation. That has to be done in memory. Or you need to change the upstream implementation of the method that returns the key selector function to return LINQ compatible expressions.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Let me see if I got the idea.
You have a CustomKey that you can define the columns to sort, in this case the programmer can do that, It's you intent right?

Comment: @EdneyBatistadaSilva: Yes.

Comment: Here is the reference - [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx). Specifically *Most of the LINQ ordering methods are supported in LINQ to Entities, with the exception of those that accept an IComparer<T>, because the comparer cannot be translated to the data source.*

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case it would be easy to use Sort method of Generic List.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx

Sort method requires the type of the list to implement `IComparable` interface and it uses the implementation of CompareTo method from `IComparable` interface. Otherwise implementation of `IComparer` also can be passed to this method.

So if your entity class is already implemeting IComparable interface then this should surely work for you. You will have to to `.ToList()` on the IQueryable result of course before you can call the Sort method on it.

```
public class Category : IComparable<Category>
{
    public int CategoryId { get; internal set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; internal set; }

    public int CompareTo(Category x)
    {
        return String.Compare(x.CategoryName, this.CategoryName, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
    }
}

List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
categories.Add(new Category {CategoryName = "Cate1"});
categories.Add(new Category {CategoryName = "Cate2"});

categories.Sort();
foreach (var cat in categories)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cat.CategoryName);
}
```

This displays me category names in reverse order based on the comparison logic I have written in the CompareTo method of `Category` Class.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I think the best way is use a custom **ExtensionMethod** to avoid any overhead of coding or unnecessary complexity to do that.

See if it implementation can help you.

First we create your customkey class that is responsable to create the statement expressions:

```
class CustomKey
{
    public CustomKey(params string[] value)
    {
        if(!value.Any())
           throw new InvalidOperationException("Select at least one Property for this operation");
        Values = new List<string>();
        Values.AddRange(value);
    }

    private List<string> Values { get; set; }

    // this method run throughout all property configured to create the expressions
    public void ForEachProperty<TSource, TKey>(Action<Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>, bool> method)
    {
        bool firstItem = true;
        Values.ForEach(f =>
        {
            var expression = CreateExpression<TSource, TKey>(f);
            method(expression, firstItem);
            firstItem = false;
        });
    }

    // this method is responsable to create each expression
    Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> CreateExpression<TSource, TKey>(string property)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "x");
        var member = typeof(TSource).GetMember(property).FirstOrDefault();
        Expression body = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, member);            
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TKey>>(Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object)), parameter);
    }
}
```

After that we create your custom ExtesionMethod, somethink like that:

```
public static class OrderByExtensionClass  
{
    // instead of try passing an expression, we pass our CustomKey object with the columns to sort.
    // than this method create the apropriate OrderBy Expression statement
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, CustomKey customKey)
    {
        // the parameter isFirst is just to control where we are to build the expression
        customKey.ForEachProperty<TSource, object>((expression, isFirst) =>
        {
            if (isFirst)
                source = source.OrderBy(expression);
            else
                source = ((IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)source).ThenBy(expression);
        });
        return ((IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)source);
    }

}
```

After that we just do:

```
 CustomKey custom = new CustomKey("Name", "Age");
 myEntityContext.People.OrderBy(custom).ToList()
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem, I think, is that OrderBy wouldn't know what to do with a complex type.  SQL Server knows how to order by primitive types, but that's about it.  You would have to do something like ...OrderBy(x=>x.Field1).ThenBy(x=>x.Field2).  You could write an extension method that takes the key, extracts the property names from the key, and builds the .OrderBy().ThenBy() expression, as long as you know what the key will be before executing the query.  Otherwise yeah, you may have to materialize the results before ordering.